# cloning and editing int[][] in java - not able to change int[][]

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, int, clone

This is my code:

```
  public Move makeMove(int[][] board)
```

(... more code ...)

```
 int[][] nextMove = board.clone(); 
  nextMove[i][j] = 1;
  int nextMaxMove = maxMove( nextMove );        

  System.out.println( next max move: " + nextMaxMove + " " + maxMove( board )  );
```

the `int[][] board` is a 8x8 board and I attempt to calculate the best move in a board game.

When I have found a list of equaly good moves I want to check what possibilities the opponent have given the different moves I can do. So I `clone()` the `board`, edit the clone `nextMove[i][j] = 1` and call the `maxMove` function on the new board.

the println is for debugging, and I get the same result for `maxMove( nextMove );` and `maxMove( board )`, this is wrong.. It seems like `nextMove` remain unchanged..

Comment: That probably means that your maxMove function is wrong...

Comment: I suggest you print out the contents of the nextMove board to see if it changed, or look at it in a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your data structure is an array of arrays - which, under the hood, is an array of references. Your clone is a *shallow* copy, so the clone contains the original arrays.
This sample code demonstrates it.

```
    int[][] x = new int[][] { { 1,3 }, { 5,7 }  };
    int[][] copyOfX = x.clone( );
    copyOfX[1][1]=13;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
    {
        System.out.println(x[i] + "/" + copyOfX[i]);
        for ( int j = 0; j < 2; j++ )
        {
            System.out.println(x[i][j] + "/" + copyOfX[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

The solution is to explicitly copy the contents of your 2-dimensional array, rather than using `.clone()`.